# How can I set a different specific header image on each page?

Tags: theme-twenty-eleven, header-image

1 am using WordPress 3.3.2 and Twenty Eleven 1.3. I would like to feature a different specific header image on each individual page, corresponding with the content of that page. At present I can get as far as uploading my own different header images, but it seems the only option is to set these to appear randomly on different pages, rather than specific ones I wish them to.

Comment: can you pst some code, have you search your exact question on google ? http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-add-different-header-image-for-every-page | http://wordpress.org/support/topic/unique-header-image-for-each-page | http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=different+specific+header+image+on+each+page+

Answer (score 1):

Instead of uploading the image as a header image, edit the page and set it as a Featured Image. In the Twenty Eleven theme, this will always display the image as the header image on that page.

Comment: the featured image needs to have minimum dimensions of 1000*288px

Comment: The featured images has to be atleast 1000px wide. Bigger images will be cropped to fit their and smaller images will get ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend a plugin for this: [WP Display Header](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-display-header/)

Allows me to upload headers via the Theme > Headers page and adds a Header selection module on the edit screen for each page and post.